# Cucumber, capybara and selenium - Submitting a form without a button

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have a test using Cucumber, capybara and selenium driver. This test should go to a form and submit it. The normal text would be

```
  Scenario: Fill form
    Given I am on the Form page
    When I fill in "field1" with "value1"
    And I fill in "field2" with "value2"
    And I press "OK"
    Then I should see "Form submited"
```

The problem is that **I don't have the OK button in the form** 
I need a way to do the "form.submit", without clicking any button or link - the same as happens when you press ENTER when you are in a form field using the browser.

I don't know how to tell capybara to submit a form. How can I do it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can access the selenium [send_keys](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#send_keys-instance_method) method to invoke a return event like

```
 find_field('field2').native.send_key(:enter)
```

Comment: Be aware that at least for me with poltergeist as a driver you have to use `:Enter`

Answer (score 19):

A simple solution:

```
When /^I submit the form$/ do
  page.evaluate_script("document.forms[0].submit()")
end
```

Worked for me with capybara-envjs. Should work with selenium as well.

Comment: There is another similar solution: [page.execute_script("$('form#your-form').submit()")](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13712246/664833) -- also, check out the note regarding [Capybara::Session#execute_script](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session:execute_script) (it says *`execute_script` should be used over `evaluate_script` whenever possible*) -- this is just a piece of information to consider.

Answer (score 10):

I just had to solve this problem myself. In webrat I had something like this:

```
Then /^I submit the "([^\"]*)" form$/ do |form_id|
  submit_form form_id
end
```

I was able to achieve the same thing with this in Capybara:

```
  Then /^I submit the "([^\"]*)" form$/ do |form_id|
    element = find_by_id(form_id)
    Capybara::RackTest::Form.new(page.driver, element.native).submit :name => nil
  end
```

Comment: This is _awesome_ because it doesn't even require javascript!  So it shouldn't depend on the driver's implementation (like everything else in the world...)  In particular, it works with no js at all.

Answer (score 5):

With the capybara Selenium driver you can do something like this:

```
within(:xpath, "//form[@id='the_form']") do
  locate(:xpath, "//input[@name='the_input']").set(value)
  locate(:xpath, "//input[@name='the_input']").node.send_keys(:return)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply put: you can't.

Some browsers will not allow you to submit a form without a submit button at all (most notably Internet Explorer <= 6). So this kind of form is a bad idea to begin with. Add a submit button and position it off the screen with CSS.

Comment: the problem is that I CAN'T add the button, because I'm testing a web site I can't change the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You may probably roll your own step (And I submit the form with the link "Ok", for example), and emulate the submit functionality yourself.

Here it is the javascript emulation dropped in Rails 3 to support "unobtrusive" (emphasis on the quotes) Javascript. The line

```
Capybara::Driver::RackTest::Form.new(driver, js_form(self[:href], emulated_method)).submit(self)
```

is probably the clue to answer your problem. The full code is [here](http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber-rails/blob/master/lib/cucumber/rails/capybara_javascript_emulation.rb)

Comment: I think it does. I'm using form submission with confirmation dialogs without problem in an application right now, and they work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you add a submit button, then hide it with CSS. Then you can test the form submission, but still get the user behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

With Webrat you can just:

```
When /^I submit the form$/ do
  submit_form "form_id"
end
```

p. 307, The RSpec Book

Answer (score 1):

The display:none solution does not work with capybara using selenium driver because selenium complains about interacting with invisible elements.
If you try the above solution you may end up seeing the following error message:

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending a newline:

```
find_field('field2').native.send_key("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hackish, but it filled a need.  I monkey-patched Capybara to support a `#submit` method on elements.

It is not robust because it naively creates the POST parameters from every input elements's `name` and `value` attributes.  (In my case, all my `<input>` elements were of type `hidden`, so it works fine).

```
class Capybara::Node::Element
  # If self is a form element, submit the form by building a
  # parameters from all 'input' tags within this form.
  def submit
    raise "Can only submit form, not #{tag_name}" unless tag_name =~ /form/i

    method = self['method'].to_sym
    url = self['action']
    params = all(:css, 'input').reduce({}) do |acc, input|
      acc.store(input['name'], input['value'])
      acc
    end

    session.driver.submit(method, url, params)
  end
end

...

form = find('#my_form_with_no_submit_button')
form.submit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
find(:css, "input[name$='login']").native.send_keys :enter
```