# Capybara - Submit a form without button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, bdd, capybara

I am trying to submit a form without button using just Capybara and Rspec (no Cucumber or Selenium, I know there is already a question about that).

I've seen there is a gist to add a method to submit a form without button:

```
module SubmitRackTestFormWithoutButton
  def submit_form!
    Capybara::RackTest::Form.new(driver, form).submit({})
  end
end
Capybara::RackTest::Node.send :include, SubmitRackTestFormWithoutButton
```

https://gist.github.com/989533, but I've not gotten it to work and I left a comment on it:

> I get undefined method `submit_form!' for #Capybara::Node::Element:...
>   actually by "Capybara::RackTest::Node.send :include,
>   SubmitRackTestFormWithoutButton" the method submit_form! is added to
>   the Node (not to the Element), but find return an Element

Do you have some idea to work out that gist, or some other solution to submit a form without button ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's possible to achieve what you want using capybara, the easier and more practical solution is to put a submit button on the form.

There is no reason to not have a button on the form, it's bad accessibility to not have a form and users that do not have a GUI or are using screen readers will have trouble submitting the form otherwise.

If you don't want the form button to be visible, can I suggest using some CSS to make it hidden:

```
<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;">
```

Comment: I think that he is testing something like search form like that above.

Comment: Thanks Mario, I agree with you, but I didn't design the GUI and for now it's not possible to change it (but I need to write the tests that use it)

Comment: No problems, just position the button off screen and then it should work :)

Comment: or just `display: none` rather than that positioning and sizing surely?

Comment: A screen reader would not announce content that is styled with display: none but it would announce content that is pushed off the page with positioning.

Answer (score 31):

All your production code should be testable, so if you add a code that is only used by the test than the test will make no sense...

Try to do this instead:

```
page.execute_script("$('form#your-form').submit()")
```

Comment: How should that work if you don't use a javascript driver? ;)

Comment: for non jQuery folks:      `page.execute_script(%q{document.querySelector("form[action='/admin/opt_outs']").submit()})`

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple solution that doesn't require capybary-webkit, qt, lmnop or whatever.

Does not require a submit button. People say you need it but whatever.

Just monkeypatch a class or two

```rb
# /spec/support/capybara.rb
  class Capybara::Session
    def submit(element)
      Capybara::RackTest::Form.new(driver, element.native).submit({})
    end
  end
```

Then you can do something like

```
require 'support/capybara'

before do
  create :lead
  create :user, :different_email
end

it 'Searchable' do
  visit users_path
  page.should have_content 'Slicer'
  page.should have_content 'Dicer'

  fill_in 'Search', with: 'dice'

  form = find '#search-form' # find the form
  page.submit form           # use the new .submit method, pass form as the argument

  page.should have_content 'Dicer'
  page.should_not have_content 'Slicer'
end
```

It's kinda like [jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19598488/4812050)'s answer on here but for his you have to define that in the middle of the test.

For this solution, you can define this in some file in the /support directory or at the beginning of that one spec, etc. It reduces the clutter in the test.

Comment: in capybara 3.38.0, this solution is broken. please check [this issue](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/2628)

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by pressing enter within the input

```
find('form input').native.send_keys :enter
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this to work in capybara 1.1.2 with:

```
  form = page.find("form")
  class << form
    def submit!
      Capybara::RackTest::Form.new(driver, native).submit({})
    end
  end
  form.submit!
```

and it looks like a similar solution is described here: http://minimul.com/submitting-a-form-without-a-button-using-capybara.html

Comment: in capybara 3.38.0, this solution is broken. please check [this issue](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/2628)

Answer (score 0):

Now You should use click_on

```
click_on 'Sign up'
```

Answer (score 0):

best solution is by using JS driver test (as mentioned [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13712246/473040)):

```
page.execute_script(%q{document.querySelector("form[action='/admin/opt_outs']").submit()})
```

**if no JS driver:**

Fact is every form should have a button, if the button should not appear in UI just hide it with `display: none` and then instead `click_button` do:

```
find('form input[type=submit]', visible: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking for the same thing and @Motine mentionned in some comments [this issue](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/2628), I just discovered here this very nice and concise way (IMO) to submit **single input** forms (like a search field) when using the **RackTest** driver (no selenium, cuprite,  javascript, etc.):

```rb
fill_in 'q', with: "search\n"
```

The trick is simply to add the `"\n"` at the end of the string and **if there's only one input in the form**, the RackTest driver will [strip the newline and submit the form](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rack_test/node.rb#L228-L231) (as if you hit enter).