# How to click enter key with cucumber test cases

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I need to click enter key of keyboard in cucumber test cases. I have used selenium web-driver.
Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: if your filling in a form see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797752/cucumber-capybara-and-selenium-submiting-a-form-without-a-button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [keys](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Keys.html) and [ActionBuilder](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html):

```
page.driver.browser.key_down(:enter).key_up(:enter).perform
```

or [send_keys](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#send_keys-instance_method):

```
find(:id, 'my_id').native.send_keys(:enter)
```

Capybara doesn't currently contain its own API for pressing keys.

Comment: I have done it with:
find(:id, 'my_id').native.send_keys("\n")